# file working in fiddle, but not worked in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My module is working fine in fiddle, but the same thing doesn't work in the browser.

I'm using jquery and bootstrap. I read the values from json file and pass that value to a textbox in every second using javascript.

I don't understand this problem.  here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/1mmwfy9q/) to my example.

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function () {
            $.getJSON('/echo/js/?js={"var1": "30", "var2": "40"}', function (data) {
                if (data.var1) {
                    $('#C1-Cycle').val(data.var1);
                }
                if (data.var2) {
                    $('#C2-Cycle').val(data.var2);
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery and Bootstrap in your file `<head>`. Thats the most common cause. If it works in JSFiddle it will work in a file.

Comment: You have errors in the html, have you tried to fix them??

Comment: Yes I've included both in head, that modules are working fine, (collapsible window), problem is with json parse only, also in js fiddle environment I've included jquery 1.11.0, my program I've include 1.11.1 version.,

Comment: Yes, some errors are there, but I did't tried to fix that., Is that cause for this proplem? @Mahdi Alkhatib

Comment: I think because there is bootstrap will be broken if there are some errors

Comment: S, I haven't close some tags but now I closed that, but still I doesn't get the out put, It may the cause., but it is working fine in fiddle, That's what makes me confused